# Find_path in Cmake doesn't work

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a custom package named `bitstream` and want to use it in upstream project.

```
--upstreamProject
|
|--src
    |-- ...(many .cpp)
    |--CmakeLists.txt
|--include
    |-- ... (..many .hpp)
|--bitstream
    |--CMakeLists.txt
    |--bitstreamConfig.cmake
    |--src
        |-- bitstream.cpp
    |--include
        |-- bitstream.hpp
```

So I write `bitstreamConfig.cmake`:

```
find_path(BITSTREAM_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES bitstream.hpp)
MESSAGE(STATUS "bitstream_include_dir: ${BITSTREAM_INCLUDE_DIR}")
find_library(BITSTREAM_LIBRARY NAMES bitstream)
MESSAGE(STATUS "BITSTREAM_LIBRARY: ${BITSTREAM_LIBRARY}")

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(BITSTREAM REQUIRED_VARS BITSTREAM_LIBRARY BITSTREAM_INCLUDE_DIR)

if(BITSTREAM_FOUND)
    set(BITSTREAM_LIBRARIES ${BITSTREAM_LIBRARY})
    set(BITSTREAM_INCLUDE_DIRS ${BITSTREAM_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

mark_as_advanced(BITSTREAM_INCLUDE_DIR BITSTREAM_LIBRARY)
```

and in upstream project I add:

```
SET(bitstream_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bitstream")
FIND_PACKAGE(bitstream)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${BITSTREAM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

in upstream project `src` I add:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${...} ${BITSTREAM_LIBRARIES})
```

but when run `cmake` I got that:

```
-- bitstream_include_dir: BITSTREAM_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- BITSTREAM_LIBRARY: BITSTREAM_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Could NOT find BITSTREAM (missing:  BITSTREAM_LIBRARY BITSTREAM_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Please tell me why cmake cannot find the correct path, thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't use cmake this way. cmake 'package finding' commands are meant to locate external packages (ones that are compiled by others - could be using cmake as well but not necessarily). So either make that bitstream package a completely separated project or make it part of your project and use cmake include instead of find package.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't give any hint to `find_path` about possible location of the searched file. By default, it searches only in system-wide dirs, and definitely does not look into *bitstream/*.

[find_path documentation page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_path.html) describes search algorithm, where all possible hints are explicitely listed.

Also, you are confused between *module* and *config* mode of [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html).

Your `bitstreamConfig.cmake`  actually implements *module* mode: it uses `find_*` commands for locate items and calls `find_package_handle_standard_args` at the end for final verdict (whether package is found or not).

But naming `*Config.cmake` implies *config* mode, which (normally) fills all variables with hardcoded values and automatically succeed.

Comment: Is it just me or find_path documentation page is too much confusing, why they couldn't just write explicit definition for each search path option instead of blasting with unclear wide jargon which only the writers and a bunch could understand. Anyway it does not help solve the issue

Comment: I find `find_path` documentation to be quite clear. Yes, it has a complex description of the search paths, but this is just a description of the complex algorithm.